# gammu-smsd inject don't send sms

Tags: raspbian, gammu

When i try to send sms with this:
gammu-smsd-inject TEXT phonenumber -text "HELLOBELLO"

Raspbian
Gammu version 1.33.0

**This is the response, but i don't get the sms.** Please help

```
gammu-smsd-inject[4297]: Using FILES service
gammu-smsd-inject[4297]: Configuring Gammu SMSD...
gammu-smsd-inject[4297]: SHM token: 0xffffffffce022f26 (-838717658)
gammu-smsd-inject[4297]: Warning: No PIN code in /etc/gammu-smsdrc file
gammu-smsd-inject[4297]: CommTimeout=60, SendTimeout=60, ReceiveFrequency=60, ResetFrequency=0, HardResetFrequency=0
gammu-smsd-inject[4297]: checks: CheckSecurity=0, CheckBattery=0, CheckSignal=1
gammu-smsd-inject[4297]: mode: Send=1, Receive=1
gammu-smsd-inject[4297]: deliveryreport = no
gammu-smsd-inject[4297]: phoneid =
gammu-smsd-inject[4297]: Inbox is "/var/spool/gammu/inbox/ outboxpath = /var/spool/gammu/outbox/" with format "standard"
gammu-smsd-inject[4297]: Outbox is "" with format "detail" and transmission format "7bit"
gammu-smsd-inject[4297]: Sent SMS moved to "/var/spool/gammu/sent/ errorsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/error/"
gammu-smsd-inject[4297]: SMS with errors moved to "/var/spool/gammu/sent/ errorsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/error/"
gammu-smsd-inject[4297]: Created outbox message OUTC20160702_053512_00_06703382072_sms0.smsbackup Written message with ID OUTC20160702_053512_00_06703382072_sms0.smsbackup
```

Comment: Where you don't get the SMS, it's not in the file mentioned in the log?

Answer (score 1):

The [gammu-smsd-inject](http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/inject.html) just adds message to the outgoing queue of the [SMSD](http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/index.html). In case you want to send SMS directly, use [gammu sendsms](http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/gammu/index.html#sending-messages).

Comment: Could you mention how one could process the queued messages?

Comment: Execute the gammu-smsd, see https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/smsd.html

Comment: Thanks! My SMSd isn't processing the queue but that's subject for another question :) Anyway I managed to use this as I just needed to send long text SMS http://jesobreira.github.io/gammu-sms-tools

Comment: Well both these can be done directly by Gammu: ``gammu sendsms TEXT -autolen 1000 -flash "Some long text..."``